# bootstrap customized layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with "Bootstrap 3.3.2" to make something like below image -

On below image link the background(grey & red bordered) is an jpeg image which is disturbing the responsive, so i am trying to make it through bootstrap using rows columns but i failed to make it responsive and according to the image link

http://www.screencast.com/t/sRimTge0jHo

Kindly help me, according to the image there will be shopping cart section to the left & search section to the right and there will be a brand scroller below search section. I am providing you code below, what i was actually doing.

```
Here is the code - 

<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="cart-bg">
                            <div class="cart-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left"></i>
                            <h3 class="pull-left">Item : 0<br/>
                            <a href="#">View Cart</a><br/>
                            <a href="#">Checkout</a></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="search-bg">
                                <form class="form-set">
                                <label><h4>Search by</h4></label>
                    <select>
                    <option value="Brand">--Brand--</option>
                    <option value="Brand1"></option>
                    <option value="Brand2"></option>
                    <option value="Brand3"></option>
                    </select>
                    <select>
                    <option value="Brand">--Technology--</option>
                    <option value="Brand1"></option>
                    <option value="Brand2"></option>
                    <option value="Brand3"></option>
                    </select>
                    <label><h4>Keyword Search</h4></label><input type="text" />
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="makeMeScrollable">
                <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="10">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                </marquee>                
            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Below is js fiddle -

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */



body{ font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; background:fff;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;}

.body-bg{ background:#fafafa repeat-y;
 box-shadow: 0 0 13px black;}
 
.clear{ clear:both;}

.top-header{background:url(../images/header_bg.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size:cover;
 }

.logo{
 float: left;
 margin: 7%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

.top-header-info{
 float:right;
 background:#c60c0c;
 margin: 5%;
 padding:1em;
}

.set-icon{display:inline;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-weight:700; font-size: 20px; 
 color:#FFF; padding: 1em;}
 
.set-icon h1{ display:inline;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-weight:700; font-size: 20px; 
 color:#FFF; padding: 1em;}
 
.navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
 
.navbar-inner {
   background: #8b171a;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 100%, 100% 6%, color-stop(0%, #c52026), color-stop(100%, #8b171a));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c52026,#8b171a);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c52026,#8b171a);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c52026,#8b171a);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c52026,#8b171a);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #c52026,#8b171a);
 border-radius:0;
} 
.navbar-inner .nav {
 float:none;
} 

.navbar {
position: relative;
min-height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-inner .nav li a {
 color: #fff;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear,opacity 0.1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear,opacity 0.1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background 0.1s linear,opacity 0.1s linear;
 -o-transition: background 0.1s linear,opacity 0.1s linear;
 transition: background 0.1s linear,opacity 0.1s linear;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;   
 opacity: .9;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px; 
 font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-inner .nav li a:hover {
 background: #f67d0f;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1;
}

.ib{ background-color:#FFF;}

.cart-bg{ display:inline-block;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color:#3c3c3c;
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
  border-top:#8b171a 4px solid;
  border-right:#8b171a 4px solid;
  border-bottom:#8b171a 4px solid;
  border-left:#8b171a 4px solid;
  }
  
.cart-icon{font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 80px;; color:#FFF;}

.cart-icon h3{ font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight:300; }

.cart-icon a{ font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight:300; color:#FFF; }

.cart-icon a:hover{font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}



.search-bg{display:inline-block;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color:#3c3c3c; 
  border-top:#8b171a 4px solid;
  border-bottom:#8b171a 4px solid;
  border-right:#8b171a 4px solid;
  width:100%
  height:auto;
  }

.form-group { margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.form-set{ padding:1%;}

.form-set label{font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px; 
 font-weight: 600; color:#FFF;}
 
.form-set i{ font-size:18px; color:#FFF; }

.makeMeScrollable{ display:inline-block;}

.makeMeScrollable img{ display:inline; padding-top:10px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<title>NJ Security</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container"><!--CONTAINER START-->
 <div class="body-bg"><!--BODY BG START-->
     <!----top-header---->
        <div class="top-header">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">                
                 <img class="img-responsive logo" src="images/logo_header.png" alt="NJ LOGO">             
       </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                 <div class="top-header-info">
                  <div class="set-icon">
                      </i><i class="fa fa-skype"></i><h1>800.973.6140 FREE</h1>
                      </div><br/>
                        <div class="set-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><h1>MONDAY - FRIDAY</h1>
                        </div><br/>
                        <div class="set-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><h1>9:30 To 05:00 AM</h1>
                  </div><br/>
                </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
     </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                 <nav class="navbar navbar-inner" role="navigation">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar ib"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar ib"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar ib"></span>
                        </button>                        
                     </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-bg">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Safes</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Access Control</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Video Surveillance</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Locks</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Automation</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                            
                            </ul>
                        </div>                    
                 </nav> 
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <div class="cart-bg">
                             <div class="cart-icon">
                 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left"></i>
                 <h3 class="pull-left">Item : 0<br/>
                    <a href="#">View Cart</a><br/>
                    <a href="#">Checkout</a></h3>
                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="search-bg">
                                 <form class="form-set">
                                        <label><h4>Search by</h4></label>
                                        <select>
                                        <option value="Brand">--Brand--</option>
                                        <option value="Brand1"></option>
                                        <option value="Brand2"></option>
                                        <option value="Brand3"></option>
                                        </select>
                                        <select>
                                        <option value="Brand">--Technology--</option>
                                        <option value="Brand1"></option>
                                        <option value="Brand2"></option>
                                        <option value="Brand3"></option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label><h4>Keyword Search</h4></label><input type="text" />
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="makeMeScrollable">
                    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="10">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo_header.png" />
                    </marquee>                
                </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>      
               
            
            
            
            
            
    
    
    
    
    
 </div><!--BODY BG END-->
</div><!--CONTAINER END-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: looks good when i apply to jsfiddle, please provide the html/css/jsfiddle sample so that we could sees what's the problem.

Comment: @Math3w.C Okay... thanks for suggestion math3w, can iprovid you link?

Comment: yes, please update the question if you want to share the link. =)

Comment: @Math3w.C with full HTML & CSS

Comment: the problem I saw is that the mobile view of the section mentioned is a mess, is this what you want to fix?

Comment: @Math3w.C yes math3w.c actually i want this section proper -

Comment: @Math3w.C http://www.screencast.com/t/sRimTge0jHo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pull-left class is the cause.

adding media query to control the css on smaller screen

```
@media (max-width:680px){
    .sec-c { height:auto;}
    .cart-icon h3 { float:none !important;}
    .makeMeScrollable { display:block;}
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/d8zfzr7n/)**

===========================================================================

New updates, Sameer, it's all about CSS tweaking.
I added few classes and styled them accordingly.
Please have a look at the new Fiddle below

**[Fillde DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/d8zfzr7n/5/)**

I strongly recommend you to refine your HTML structure and the default CSS used.

Comment: Hello "Math3w.c" thankyou you helped me with that but actually by mistake i first upload the wrong fiddle but just after some second i updated the correct fiddle, so can you kindly help me with correct fiddle. Sorry it was my mistake. Can you kindly help?

Comment: Could you generate the "correct" version of the fiddle and share the link here? And please specify the issue. Thanks =)

Comment: Hello "Math3w.c" Here is the correct fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/d8zfzr7n/3/ and the issue is actually i want the shopping cart and search section like this image - http://www.screencast.com/t/sRimTge0jHo  and below the search link there will be a "brand scroller" . In the image i have shared you can see "the grey and red bordered" background of cart and search section ... that is an image" but i want that to code that background also that should be responsive" I hope you got my point.

Comment: @math3w.Ckindly help.

Comment: @SameerKorde, I've updated the answer, just giving you the idea on how it should be done, you'll have to do the details on your own.(simply css tweaking). See DEMO 2

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt help, i have checked the fiddle demo you have given, it helped me alot. Also as you suggested i will refine my HTML & CSS and will work on those. In fact i should learn the bootstrap more. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Mathw3.C Also, i wanted to vote you. But my reputation doesn't  allow me for that, as i got increased my reputation, will vote you.